# function "map" with casting crashes in release, but works in debug

Tags: swift, exception, dictionary, casting

I tried to do some testing on "release" and somehow my app keeps crashing at places with the combination of the function `map` and typecasting, which in this case is from `NSNumber` to `Int`. So I tested a little bit:

```
var test11: NSNumber = 10
var test12 = test11 as Int               // this works

var test21: [NSNumber] = [1,2,3,4,5]
var test22 = test21.map { $0 as Int }    // throws an exception

var test31: [NSNumber] = [1,2,3,4,5]
var test32 = test31.map { Int($0) }      // this works
```

In debug mode, all of these methods works just fine. Is there any reason why the second method doesn't work in release mode?

Comment: There are some copy/paste errors in your code (nsnumber undefined, test31 used before defined). – Apart from that, it seems to be a compiler bug and works as expected with Xcode 6.3 beta 4.

Comment: Using a playground here, Xcode 6.2. Once all the code errors are solved, everything works ok

Comment: Sorry, fixed the copy & paste errors. @DiegoFreniche: it's working in debug mode but once you test it in release mode, it will throw an exception.

Comment: Did you check with Xcode 6.3 beta 4 ?

Comment: No, I haven't. I've read some things don't work on iOS 8.2 yet so I haven't tried it yet. Would you recommend it 6.3 beta 4 though?

Comment: I don't have any recommendations. (Xcode 6.3 brings a lot of fixes and performance improvements, but it is still beta ...) But you can install Xcode 6.3  in parallel with your Xcode 6.2, and if you suspect a compiler bug in 6.2 (I do!), you can double-check with 6.3.